# Files related/required to a digital certificate

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I am new to digital certification and I am trying to understand it as well as get my domain certified.

I know this question may be broad, but can someone give me a general idea of the usage of the following files and how they are related?

- `xxx.cer`
- `xxx.csr`
- `xxx.JKS`
- `xxx.p12`

===

to add on, i am reading
https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

what is per,der and pem format ? and how are they link to .cer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @SmokeDispenser is quite concrete and accurate. I will try to provide a bit of additional background in case you need it.

A **private key** is the most critical piece of data of your list. If someone gets access to it or manages to use it, the certification is pointless. As a result, private keys are often stored in files known as **keystores**. The content is usually password protected (technically it can support other protection modes, but I've only seen the case of passwords). This is important and often mishandled: **do not send the password via email or other insecure mechanism, nor keep copies of them around**. The extensions `.p12` and `.jks` belong to two formats of keystore. If you work with Windows, you might find also the extension `.pfx`, but it's practically the same as `.p12`.

Since you cannot distribute around your keystore and still don't have a certificate, you have to send a **Certificate Signature Request (CSR)** to the certificate authority. The `.csr` file contains public information about your key and your identity.

As a response, the CA replies to your request with a **certificate** (`.cer` or `.crt`). It contains all your information, including your public key, some data about the CA and it is signed by the CA. Note that a certificate is only valid if you have a *certificate chain* (i.e. the system that validates the certificate, probably the browser, has the certificates of the CA stored).

Finally, depending of the usage you intend for the certificate, you might also need to be aware of the **Certificate Revokation List** (`.crl` files). If a certificate is revoked (i.e. it is no longer valid for whatever reason), that action will be reflected on the CRL. When verifying a certificate, one should ensure that it is not in there. Nowadays, most reputable CAs offer also an online status check via the **OCSP** protocol.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful add-on, i have slightly amended my original question. please kindly take a look

Comment: @Noob They are just encodings and shouldn't bother you in high level terms. However, you can take a look to my answer here about them: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33636/how-is-the-rsa-publickeyn-e-transformed-into-a-textfile-allowing-its-public/33637#33637

Comment: @sergios,  thanks for the link, will try to digest it.  just want to be sure, when we talk about encoding of the cert, we are just talking about the format/internal presentation of the cert,  and that is before the cert get sign by a CA ?

Comment: Exactly. Most robust tools can handle all the alternative encodings transparently.

Comment: thanks! so this "encoding'  of the format der,pem is nothing to do with the "digital signing/encryption" of the cert itself by the CA - yea ?  just wanna be sure.

Comment: Exactly. You can take an already signed certificate and parse it from PEM to DER or import it into a keystore without affecting its validity.

Comment: pardon me for asking over here.  - when parsing 1 cert from 1 encoding to another,   is the digital signature of the ca consider as part of the cert ?
my basic understanding is signing a cert means signing a hash of the cert with the ca private key. if the encoding is different after parsing, the hash is gonna be different as well, isn't it - wouldn't we need to get the ca to resign the cert?

Comment: The hash is calculated over the rawest form. For instance, if you have $x$, $base64-enc(x)$ or $hex-enc(x)$, you can calculate the $hash(x)$ from any of them (decoding first, in the second and third case). The validity remains because the data is the same, although encoded differently.

Comment: not sure i would really understand that.. given my level, can i just say that the parsing of cert from 1 encoding to another includes the digital signature of the ca as well ?

Comment: Yes. As I said: don't worry about the encoding, because it's transparent.

Answer (score 5):

To put it as simple as possible:

- a `cer` is a certificate. Think: a (your) public key, signed by a CA (certificate authority)
- a `csr` is a certificate signing request. Think:

  > Here, CA, this is my public key and a proof that I do in fact have the private key for that public key
- `p12` is a container format that holds various things. Often, and probably in your case a key pair (a private and corresponding public key), often encrypted itself.
- `JKS` is the java keystore format. Like p12, it is a container, which can hold multiple keys and/or certificates.  A keystore which holds only certificates is called a truststore.
- DER and PEM are two different encodings used to represent a certificate.

Comment: hi smoke, thanks for the straight to the point and easy to understand answers. i have amended my original question , please kindly take a look

Comment: sorry, just changed it.

Comment: I edited my answer. For how to convert between DER and PEM, feel free to google yourself as I'm on the run;)

Comment: thanks, so the encoding of a cert has nothing to do with the encryption/digitally signing of the cert by the CA yea ?

Comment: Not per-se it's just two ways of expressing the same data, whereas one allows "easy" binary consumption and one easy textual transmission